# Not able to understand LINQ extension methods

Tags: c#, linq

I am not able to interpret the following statement:

```
var myResults = new List<bool>();
myResults.Add(this.myWorkers.All(c => other.Workers.Any(cc => c.Equals(cc))));
```

I had a look at [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/04/21/c.net-little-wonders-any-and-all.aspx) which explains Any and All separately. However I am not too sure how interpret a nested LINQ.

Comment: Any means match condition at least one. All means all elements match condition.

Comment: This statement checks if `myWorkers` is a subset of `other.Workers`, and can be expressed more simply with `!myWorkers.Except(other.Workers).Any()`.

Answer (score 2):

`this.myWorkers.All(c => other.Workers.Any(cc => c.Equals(cc)))` returns `true` if every object in `myWorkers` collection is presented in `Workers` collection of `other`.

you can rewrite this expression with loops:

```
bool All = true;
foreach (var c in this.myWorkers)
{

    bool Any = false;
    foreach (var cc in other.Workers)
        if (c.Equals(cc))
        {
            Any = true;
            break;
        }

    if (!Any)
    {
        All = false;
        break;
    }
}

myResults.Add(All);
```

Answer (score 1):

Adds a boolean to the list `myResults` indicating whether or not each item in `myWorkers` collection is reference equal to any item in `other.Workers` collection.

---

The same code can be rewritten without LINQ as:

```
var myResults = new List<bool>();
bool all = true;
foreach (var c in myWorkers)
{
    bool any = false;
    foreach (var cc in other.Workers)
    {
        if (c.Equals(cc))
        {
            any = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!any)
    {
        all = false;
        break;
    }
}
myResults.Add(all);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we are use method syntax (Lamda expression)

Lamda expression work with collection.

```
myResults.Add(this.myWorkers.All(c => other.Workers.Any(cc => c.Equals(cc))));
```

Here

**Add()** method is used of add element into **myResults** collection.
**All()** method used for traverse all the element of collection.
**Any()** method used for match element with condition if any match found then its skip rremain elements.

Expression return **true** if any element in collection match with **cc**